# R: Performing an operation on a vector element twice in one go

Tags: r

I have a vector of values

```
theVector <- c(1,5,2,10)
```

And a vector of values that represent indexes

```
indexes <- c(2,3,4)
```

Now I want to perform an operation on `theVector` at the indexes described in `indexes`. For example

```
theVector[indexes] <- theVector[indexes] + 2
theVector
```

output:

```
[1]  1  7  4 12
```

Exactly what I wanted. But what if I want to do the operation twice on some index let's say

```
indexes <- c(2,3,4,4)
theVector[indexes] <- theVector[indexes] + 2
theVector
```

that returns the same output:

```
[1]  1  7  4 12
```

instead of what i want:

```
[1]  1  7  4 14
```

Is it really necessary to use a loop or `apply()`? I'm looking for something efficient.

Comment: What about this: `theVector[unique(indexes)] <- theVector[unique(indexes)] + (2 * table(indexes))`